# firefox - fill background with gradientt

Tags: css

hi there i am using the following code to create a gradient background in `firefox`... but the problem is that the gradient fills the page alright but it repeats...

```
<body style="background-image:linear-gradient(#eee,#ddd); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);">
```

and below is the result of the above code

[image: the result of the above code]

i want the gradient to stretch and fill the whole page... how can i do this.... any help would be appreciated thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried the below code and it worked

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#eee,#ddd); height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a css file for a crossbrowser gradient:

```
body {
    background: #2f2727; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2727 0%, #1a82f7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2f2727), color-stop(100%,#1a82f7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f2727', endColorstr='#1a82f7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[Gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to simply add background to `HTML` element and set its height to 100%:

```
html {
    /* and dont forget the prefixes ;) */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 100%) no-repeat;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Caja9/